# How to get value from dynamic input in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, angular5

I'm getting below JSON from api

```
{  
   "status":"true",
   "select":[  
      {  
         "Type":"MARKET_WORKING",
         "Question":"WHICH BRAND COUNTER IS IT?",
         "option1":"USPA",
         "option2":"HANES",
         "option3":"USPA & HANES ",
         "option4":""
      }
   ],
   "text":[  
      {  
         "Type":"MARKET_WORKING",
         "Question":"WHAT IS THE STOCK QTY AVAILABLE OF INNERWEARS?",
         "option1":"INNERWEARS TOP ",
         "option2":"INNERWEARS BOTTOM ",
         "option3":"",
         "option4":""
      },
      {  
         "Type":"MARKET_WORKING",
         "Question":"WHAT IS THE STOCK QTY AVAILABLE OF COMFORTWEAR?",
         "option1":"COMFORT WEAR TOP",
         "option2":"COMFORT WEAR BOTTOM",
         "option3":"",
         "option4":""
      }
   ]
}
```

Where in text part I'm getting two questions where each have two answer with option1 and option2 which will write in input field. How can I get this value of dynamically created inputs?. I tried with adding `class` to each input and trying to get value of these inputs by `.val()` using `jQuery`. But the value is getting blank. Not getting how to do this with angular 4

below is my ts code.

```
  submitkey()
  {
      this.brandSelect = this.selectedOption;
      this.stock_qty_innerwears_top = $('.INNERWEARS.TOP').val();
      console.log(this.stock_qty_innerwears_top);
      this.stock_qty_innerwears_bottom = $('.INNERWEARS.BOTTOM').val();
      this.comfort_wear_top = $('.COMFORT.WEAR.TOP').val();
      this.comfort_wear_bottom = $('.COMFORT.WEAR.BOTTOM').val();


       let params={
                    eid:this.user.id,
                    brand:this.brandSelect,
                    type_col:'MARKET_WORKING',
                    STOCK_QTY_INNERWEARS_TOP:this.stock_qty_innerwears_top,
                    STOCK_QTY_INNERWEARS_BOTTOM:this.stock_qty_innerwears_bottom,
                    COMFORT_WEAR_TOP:this.comfort_wear_top,
                    COMFORT_WEAR_BOTTOM:this.comfort_wear_bottom,

                    }   
      this.apiService.add_mwork(params).subscribe((res)=>{
                    // console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

and below is .html code

```
  <div class="field-group" *ngFor="let mworkq of textq">
    <div class="label-cust">
          {{mworkq.Question}}
          <ion-input class="{{mworkq.option1}}" type="text" placeholder="{{mworkq.option1}}" ></ion-input>
          <ion-input class="{{mworkq.option2}}" type="text" placeholder="{{mworkq.option2}}" ></ion-input>            
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079111/angular-5-how-to-call-a-function-when-html-element-is-created-with-ngfor/51079312#51079312

This will help you to know one of the ways by which we can manage dynamic html elements using angular life cycle hooks.
I hope it helps you.

Comment: M calling this on submit button which is in html file