# Angular 4 innerHTML removes directive from the element

Tags: html, angular, angular-template

I am trying to set innerHTML in a div but the directive used in the text is ignored. I am not sure if it is a invalid attribute(according to HTML) So below is my code:

```html
<table class="table">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div [innerHTML]="issue.longText"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

the value of issue.longText in component.ts is:

```html
<ul><li>20/07/2018 - Hello!This is the test issue on click on it(<span [issueOpener]='{"recordId": 4, "page":1}'>link</span>)</li></ul>
```

And when I inspect the div I've got the following:

`<ul><li>20/07/2018 - Hello!This is the test issue on click on it(<span>link</span>)</li></ul>`

Directive **issueOpener** is removed from the span. So how can I prevent this directive? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is wanted behavior and here is why : when you write Typescript code, **you aren't writing your final application**. Your code needs to be compiled first.

To be compiled, your code goes through a process ran by the CLI : during this process, the compiler **replaces every piece of Angular code with valid JS code**.

This means for instance, that `(click)` event become `onclick` (This one's not entirely true, but that pictures the point I'm making).

When you use innerHtml, you write **final code** : it won't be compiled. It's not Angualr code, so it won't work like you hoped.

Answer (score 0):

Ajay you can do one thing and that will surely work in your case.
Please refer following link:-

[Angular 5 - How to call a function when HTML element is created with *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079111/angular-5-how-to-call-a-function-when-html-element-is-created-with-ngfor/51079312#51079312)

You can write logic on ngAfterViewInit() that should be responsible for adding directive at the HTML which is now loaded so that directive can be added dynamically.
Refer:-
    [How to dynamically add a directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298168/how-to-dynamically-add-a-directive)